# No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"links"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

**routes**

```
   resources :links, only: [:new, :create, :index, :destroy]
```

**links_conttroller**

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
before_filter :signed_in_user

def new
@user = current_user
@tags = @user.tags
@link = Link.new
end

def create
@link = Link.new(params[:link])
if @link.save
  flash[:success] = "Link created!"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  render 'new'
end
end

def index
@links = Link.paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def destroy
@link.destroy
redirect_to links_path
end

end
```

**html.erb**

```
<li>
<span class="location_info"> From Tag: <%= link.from_tag.ref %></span>
<span class="location_info"> To Tag: <%= link.to_tag.ref %></span>
<span class="location_info"> Cost: <%= link.value %>
| <%= link_to "delete", link, method: :delete,
                                 data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %></span>
</li>
```

Why am I getting this error?

[image: grep]

Comment: the destroy action requires an `id` so it can search the record (in your case, it needs an id to search for @link)

Comment: you should look at the code where you get this error.  it is most probably in the view where you try to add a delete link.

Comment: `link` is most probably a new record (it has no `id`) which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: the delete link is in a partial for an index page, so it definitely has an id!

Comment: do a `<%= link.inspect -%>` in you partial so we can see what the link actually looks like. and a `rake routes | grep -i link` just to be sure...

Comment: I have added the result of the rake routes

Comment: without looking at the whole code, we won't have any idea what's wrong. it will be your responsibility to check things out but it looks like you're sure of how your code works. i suggest you check out again your stack trace to make sure that it's pointing to the partial you're using in your index file and to make sure that all links in your index file has an id. it's the least you can do for us who are trying to help you out.

Comment: this is the link inspect 

#<Link id: 1, from_id: 1, to_id: 2, value: 2, created_at: "2013-03-10 19:21:10", updated_at: "2013-03-10 19:21:10">

Comment: & my partial is definitely working, cause if I leave out the destroy route in the controller and routes class then the partial loads fine with my information, but when I add :destroy and def destroy it gives me the error above

Comment: here is a link to my full code
https://github.com/eoghanmiggan/nfc_campus

Answer (score 0):

Your code on github is different from the one you have here but, 
don't you need to find the link in the `destroy` action first then destroy it?
As it is now it calls `destroy` on an empty `@link` variable.

As the links and routes looks good, my guess you should have destroy action like this:

```
def destroy
  @link= Link.find(params[:id])
  @link.destroy
  redirect_to links_path
end
```

unless you have a filter in the app somewhere that finds the @link object. Update your code on github so I can downloaded it and install it on my computer to investigate more if the above solution is not working.